# How can I accept third party cookies to selenium chromedriver in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Python selenium chromedriver to open a specific website which says "please accept third party cookies to access the website". How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an http/standard feature, so there isn't a standard way of doing it. You need to write code that does it for each site you're accessing. Since you're using selenium, it's not difficult to just click the "I accept" button on those sites.